# How to cut a string after last occurrence of a substring in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

For a string like this,

"By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service."

I want to cut the string from last occurrence of 'our' to get the result: " Terms of Service."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bash` you can do this:

```
s="By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service."
echo "${s##*our }"
```

```
Terms of Service.
```

If you cannot use `bash` for some reason then this `awk` should work:

```
awk -F 'our ' '{print $NF}' <<< "$s"
```

```
Terms of Service.
```

Comment: The `${parameter##word}` notation is [part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02), not just a bashism.